# Get array of coma separated integer from array of string in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub

I have the array of string like,

```
a = ["13", "---\n- '5'\n- 19\n- 20\n", "---\n- 21\n", "---\n- 21\n- 22\n", "---\n- 21\n- 22\n"]
```

but i want converted array like,

```
a = ["13","5,19,20","21","21,22","21,22"]
```

I have already tried Regexp and gsub, but i didn't get array as i want.
Please help if any one know.

Comment: post the gsub command you tried.

Comment: any negatives in the data?

Comment: @AvinashRaj In loop i was doing like this `b << c.gsub(/[^0-9]/,' ').strip` and as output i.e `["13", "5    19   20", "21", "21   22", "21   22"]`. But i got answer from shivam.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a YAML file?

Comment: @Stefan No i am getting this data from database not from YAML file.

Comment: @rick interesting, because `puts a` prints a valid YAML structure.

Comment: @Stefan you are right but i want to execute loop on output array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex scanning for integers and joining them with `,`

```
a = ["13", "---\n- '5'\n- 19\n- 20\n", "---\n- 21\n", "---\n- 21\n- 22\n", "---\n- 21\n- 22\n"]
a.map{|b| b.scan(/\d+/).join(',')}
# => ["13", "5,19,20", "21", "21,22", "21,22"]
```

Note: Assuming no negatives in input array (as asked in a comment)

Comment: you can use `/-?\d+/` to include the negatives as well

Comment: @xlembouras yup we can use that as well. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @xlembouras and avinash thanks for adding more value to my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it by joining, using `gsub`, then splitting and formating:

```
a.join(',').gsub(/[^\d,]/, ' ').split(',').map { |s| s.split.join(',') }
  #=> ["13", "5,19,20", "21", "21,22", "21,22"]
```